# Facebook comments for each users

Tags: facebook, comments

Ok when you use this code:

```
<div id="comments">
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#appId=YOUR_API_KEY&amp;xfbml=1"></script>
<fb:comments href="http://www.tiffanyjonesdesigns.com/facebook/countdown/visitor.php" num_posts="100" width="650">
</fb:comments>
</div>
```

You have to enter your app ID, but what if I want the comments to be unique to the user who use my app? Is it possible to shows comments depending on the user ID?

Thank a lot for your help!

Comment: I deleted the previous question that contained sensitive information.

Answer (score 1):

The way to do this is to use the `href` attribute in `fb:comments`. You can give each of your users a different, unique `href` so that the comments are saved separately (like comments on different articles of a news site). Be aware, however, that this isn't really "secure", and it won't prevent user A from looking at user B's comments once user A figures out what your URL scheme is and what user B's identifier/unique `href` is.

Comment: I tried this but it still give me the same comments on all different page. I think its because the script source for the comments is linked with my API KEY : http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#appId=YOUR_API_KEY&amp;xfbml=1 .

Comment: Ok I found a way to make it works by using xid parameter in fb:comments

Comment: Found the answer there : http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?pid=271014#p271014